# DataGridView to XML with preserved datatypes

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to save and load XML string from and to a DataGridView.
With following code I can do that but datatypes of columns is lost and whole grid is then filled with only strings. In this situation formatting and sorting don't work good anymore.

Is here something I can do to keep original datatypes during showed proccess?
I would like solution which woud be usable for my other projects to.

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.IO

    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            dgv.Columns.Add("col0", "col0")
            dgv.Columns(0).ValueType = Type.GetType("Integer")
            dgv.Columns.Add("col1", "col1")
            dgv.Columns.Add("col2", "col2")
            dgv.Columns(2).ValueType = Type.GetType("Double")
            dgv.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"

            dgv.Rows.Add({CInt("1"), "John", CDbl("0,11")})
            dgv.Rows.Add({CInt("2"), "Mary", CDbl("2,8")})
            dgv.Rows.Add({CInt("3"), "Mike", CDbl("10,125")})
            dgv.Rows.Add({CInt("4"), "Suzy", CDbl("2")})
        End Sub

        Private Sub dgv_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgv.Leave

            If dgv.Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
                Dim dsa As DataSet = New DataSet()
                dsa.DataSetName = "xdgv"
                Dim dxs As DataTable = GetDataTableFromDGV(dgv)
                dsa.Tables.Add(dxs)
                ''save xml from dgv content to textbox
                TextBox1.Text = GenerateXML(dsa)
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Function GenerateXML(ByVal xds As DataSet) As String

            Dim obj As New StringWriterUtf8()
            Dim xmlstring As String
            xds.WriteXml(obj, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
            xmlstring = obj.ToString()

            Return xmlstring
        End Function

        Private Function GetDataTableFromDGV(ByVal dgv As DataGridView) As DataTable

            Dim dt = New DataTable()

            Dim t As Integer = 0
            For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
                If column.Visible Then
                    dt.Columns.Add(dgv.Columns(t).Name)
                    t += 1
                End If
            Next

            Dim cellValues As Object() = New Object(dgv.Columns.Count - 1) {}
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
                If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
                        cellValues(i) = If(row.Cells(i).Value Is Nothing, String.Empty, row.Cells(i).Value)
                    Next
                    dt.Rows.Add(cellValues)
                End If
            Next

            Return dt
        End Function

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            ''load xml from textbox back to dgv
            dgv.Rows.Clear()

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
                Try
                    Dim Stream As StringReader = New StringReader(TextBox1.Text)
                    Dim xreader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(Stream)
                    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
                    ds.ReadXml(xreader)
                    For Each table As DataTable In ds.Tables
                        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                            dgv.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray())
                        Next row
                    Next table
                    ds = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("xmlFoo: " + ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class StringWriterUtf8
        Inherits System.IO.StringWriter
        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Encoding() As Encoding
            Get
                Return Encoding.UTF8
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
```

For sucessfully running this code you would need new project with Form1 on it which contains DataGridView="dgv", Text box="TextBox1" and Button="Button1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new solution which will require some reworking on your behalf. Instead of populating the datagridview, populate a datatable and use this to do the binding and serialization.

Here is some example code which shows the table being created, bounding to the gridview, serialized and deserialized with its types intact.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Src")
    dt.Columns.Add("col0", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("col2", GetType(Double))

    dt.Rows.Add({CInt("1"), "John", CDbl("0,11")})
    dt.Rows.Add({CInt("2"), "Mary", CDbl("2,8")})
    dt.Rows.Add({CInt("3"), "Mike", CDbl("10,125")})
    dt.Rows.Add({CInt("4"), "Suzy", CDbl("2")})

    dgv.DataSource = dt
    dgv.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"

    Dim file = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    dt.WriteXml(file, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

    Dim dt2 = New DataTable
    dt2.ReadXml(file)

    dgv.DataSource = dt2
End Sub
```

---

Your modified GenerateXml function:

```
Private Function GenerateXML(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Dim obj As New StringWriterUtf8()
    Dim xmlstring As String
    dt.WriteXml(obj, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
    xmlstring = obj.ToString()
    TextBox1.Text = xmlstring
    Return xmlstring
End Function
```

---

Independent Schemas

```
    Dim file = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Dim schema = "c:\temp\test.xsd"
    dt.WriteXml(file, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
    dt.WriteXmlSchema(schema)

    Dim dt2 = New DataTable
    dt2.ReadXmlSchema(schema)
    dt2.ReadXml(file)
```

Comment: Hm, not exactly how I want but works. Is here any way to use string(textbox) instead of file?

Comment: I've just modified your GenerateXml function to use datatable instead. This approach should drastically reduce the amount of code you've got.

Comment: Yes, that works good. I just want to use string instead of file. This part with new GenerateXML goes good. I am also successfuly clear the DataTable and reload it from Textbox, then rebind to dgv again. That mean that I work wit one data table instead of two... Much better solution then was my initial. Thank you very much. But I'm wondering why I cannot read proper type od dgv column anyway... We would solve that next time :)

Comment: And finally, one more theoretical question. I store that XML in database. There will be much of thoses xml strings. Is it possible to have schema also in string for use on the fly. I mean not to store it with every xml string. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, its possible. There's a writexmlschema method you can use but I'm away from my machine so don't have the details. However, the question is should you do this? Why not save the data away as records and query them as needed. No need for XML serialisation at all.

Comment: That was existed way of storing things which I can't change now. Maybe somewhere in the future. OK, thanks for an answer. I will surf a bit for a "plugable" schema.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot. I get it working with independent schema. From file and from string too!